# Write multiple occurences under single cell in SQL for VBA

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, concatenation

I am working on SQL for VBA.
Usually, if we have multiple occurrences of the desired condition, each of the occurrences will be written on different cells, like the code below:

```
"SELECT CPID " & _
    "FROM LCOND_LAST " & _
    "WHERE WELL ='" & sht1.Cells(i + 3, 8) & "'  " & _
    "ORDER CPID"
```

Which will gives output:

[image]

Notice that there are 2 cells to write two occurrences.

My question is, can we just write them on single cells only?
Is there any function that allows us to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DISTINCT` as follows:

```
"SELECT WELL, CPID " & _
    "FROM LCOND_LAST " & _
    "WHERE WELL ='" & sht1.Cells(i + 3, 8) & "'  " & _
    "ORDER BY PSWELLCOND_LAST.CPID"
```

`DISTINCT` is used to filter duplicate rows

Learn more about `DISTINCT` from [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-select-distinct/).

-- Update

You can use the `CHR(10)` -- newline and aggregate it as follows:

```
"SELECT LISTAGG(CPID, CHR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CPID) " & _
    "FROM LCOND_LAST " & _
    "WHERE WELL ='" & sht1.Cells(i + 3, 8) & "'  "
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated the problems. But I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: It worked bro. Thank you so much for this trick. It really helped me!